# Basic Android tip calculator

Tags: java, android

I'm taking a course in mobile app development and one of the first projects was a tip calculator.  I tried to adapt the code in the book (which used a slider) to one with four buttons.

This code compiles and runs OK, but when I click on the buttons (for 15%, 18%, 20%, and 22%) it doesn't seem to run the calculations -- the tip and total amounts show up as 0.00 and the eachperson (what each person pays if you split the bill) shows up as NaN (Not a number.)  The code is simple enough, so this is probably a simple error...but I don't know where it is and neither does the teacher.  My code is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final NumberFormat currencyFormat = 
          NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
       private static final NumberFormat percentFormat = 
          NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
 private double billAmount = 0.0;
 private double diners;
 private double tipPercent;
 private double tipAmount;
 private double totalAmount;
 private double eachPerson;
 private TextView billTV;
 private TextView tipTV;
 private TextView totalTV;
 private TextView eachTV;
 private TextView dinersTV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b15= (Button) findViewById(R.id.fifteenButton);
    Button b18= (Button) findViewById(R.id.eighteenButton);
    Button b20= (Button) findViewById(R.id.twentyButton);
    Button b22= (Button) findViewById(R.id.twentytwobutton);
    b15.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    b18.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    b20.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    b22.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);

    billTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.billAmount);
    tipTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipAmount);
    totalTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalAmount);
    eachTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eachPays);
    dinersTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diners);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() 
{

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.fifteenButton :
        tipPercent = .15;

        break;
    case R.id.eighteenButton :
         tipPercent = .18;

        break;
    case R.id.twentyButton :
       tipPercent = .20;

        break;  
    case R.id.twentytwobutton :
        tipPercent = .22;
         break;

    }
    tipAmount = (billAmount * tipPercent );
    totalAmount = billAmount + tipAmount;
    eachPerson = totalAmount / diners;

    tipTV.setText(currencyFormat.format(tipAmount));
    totalTV.setText(currencyFormat.format(totalAmount));
    eachTV.setText(currencyFormat.format(eachPerson));
  }
};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is the line causing the problem `private double billAmount = 0.0;` , just supply a value for the `billAmount`,

here for example what you can do:

```
EditText billEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.billEditText);
```

and at runtime take the value and assign it to billAmount,

```
billAmount = Double.parseDouble(billEditText.getText().toString);
```

and then you do all calculations fine. **Or**  if you meant by `billTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.billAmount);` is where you take the billAmount as presupplied you have to convert it like this:

```
billAmount = Double.parseDouble(billTV.getText().toString());
```

Comment: @KurtW please mark the answer as correct to let others get benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is creating for this line...

```
private double billAmount = 0.0;
```

Since primarily,you are assigning `0.0` to `billAmount` and didn't update it anymore that's why, when your multiplying any amount with it...the resulted multiplication will be `0.0`. So, change the value of `billAmount`...following code will give you correct result.

```
tipAmount = (billAmount * tipPercent );
totalAmount = billAmount + tipAmount;
```